# How do i get my progressbar to update in Flask stream_with_context

Tags: python-3.x, flask-sqlalchemy

i'm creating my first web application with Flask. im currently having some issues getting my Progressbars to update. The number of bars to update is number of items the user selects in the dropdown menu, when filling in the import.html form.
This is what im trying to achieve

1. User fills out out an html form and on submit, selected values get redirected to /progress
2. /progress get the parameters, renders an html progress page and updates the progressbars rendered on that page

The first step works without any issues, i can Post/get the parameter and also display them in progress.html

when i run the generate() below, i get a generator object 'selected': <generator object generate at 0x00000160415C2A50> which i still dont know how to display it in my progress.html and to update the progressbar.

What is actually missing in my code to be able to update the progressbars in intervals of 10?

I know it sounds simple and i think it is, but there is something im missing and i hope you guys could help. Please find below my sample code

app.py

```
@app.route("/imports", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def import_tickers():
    if request.method == "POST":
        selections = request.form.getlist('selected')
        return redirect(url_for('progress', selections=selections))
    else:
        return render_template('imports.html')

def generate(selects):
    x = 0
    p = {}
    while x <= 100:
       # Do some stuff in the background, and increase the value by 10
        for t in selects:
            p[t] = min(x, 100)
        prog_data = "data:" + json.dumps(p) + "\n\n"
        yield prog_data
        x = x + 10
        time.sleep(0.5)        
def stream_template(template_name, **context):
        app.update_template_context(context)
        t = app.jinja_env.get_template(template_name)
        rv = t.stream(context)
        print("context-->", context)
        rv.disable_buffering()
        return rv
    @ app.route("/progress", methods=["GET"])
    def progress():
        if request.method == "GET":
            selections = request.args.getlist('selections')
            selected = generate()
        return Response(stream_with_context(stream_template('progress.html', selected=selected, selections=selections)))
```

progress.html

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Bluechips</th>
            <th>Progress</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for t in selections%}
        <tr>
            <td>{{t}}</td>
            <td>
                <div class="progress" style="height:30px">
                    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated" style="width:60%;height:30px"
                        aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" id="prog_{{t}}">
                        <span class="progress-bar-label" id="prog_{{t}}_label">0%</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        {%endfor%}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

import.html Form

```
 <form class="form-inline" method="POST" action="#" onsubmit="import_assets()">
```

JavaScript

```
<script>
        function import_assets() {
            console.log("opening the SSE connection")
            var source = new EventSource("/progress");
            source.onmessage = function (event) {
                sent_data = JSON.parse(event.data)
                console.log(event.data)
                // sent_data = event.data
                console.log(sent_data)
                var done = true
                for (i in sent_data) {
                    console.log(i, sent_data[i])
                    pb_id = "#prog_" + i
                    $(pb_id).css('width', sent_data[i] + '%').attr('aria-valuenow', sent_data[i]);
                    lb_id = pb_id + "_label"
                    $(lb_id).text(sent_data[i] + '%');
                    if (sent_data[i] < 99)
                        done = false

                }

                if (done) {
                    console.log("Closing the SSE connection")
                    source.close()
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Thanks in advance...